Add Tenant Filter to Spring authorization Server
I want to add a TenantIdentificationFilter in the Spring Authorization Server.
I am trying to configure it as mentioned in this post.
This however is producing the error Cannot resolve symbol 'OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter'.
The TenantIdentificationFilter is a filter class that extends from `OncePerRequestFilter. what is the correct way to configure this Filter so update my TenantContext which is a thread local.
Below is my Spring security chain configuration.
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SpringsecurityConfig {

    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer;

    // allow all actuator endpoints and without auth
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .securityMatcher(authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher())
                .with(authorizationServerConfigurer,
                        (authorizationServer) ->
                                authorizationServer.oidc(Customizer.withDefaults())
                )

                .addFilterAfter(new TenantIdentificationFilter(), OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}


To use OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class  you need to add this dependency:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

